# Trouble setting session attribute in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to set a string as a session attribute in a jsp as seen below.

```
session.setAttribute("error","You must be logged in to access this page.");
```

I then have a pop up that displays the message in the code below.

```
<input id='error' type='hidden' value=<%=(String)session.getAttribute("error")%>>
<script>
    if(document.getElementById('error').value != "null"){
        window.alert(document.getElementById('error').value);
    }
</script>
```

But when I test this the pop up window only displays the word You.

[image]

Comment: try it in another browser i think it may be an issue in eclipse built in browser

Comment: If the answers worked for you, can you please accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the value in ''. This should work

`<input id='error' type='hidden' value='<%=(String)session.getAttribute("error")%>'/>`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but try this:

```
String value = "You must be logged in to access this page."    
session.setAttribute("error", value);
```

It seems you already getting first string "You" so it might be better if you save whole sentence in object(String).

Sorry for putting it in answer section as I cannot comment yet(need 50 points to comment by rules).

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a javascript variable and use that instead?

```
    <script>
    var errorMessage = '<%=(String)session.getAttribute("error")%>';

    if(errorMessage != null && errorMessage.length > 0){
        window.alert(errorMessage);
    }
</script>
```